# Сохранение файла XML на сервере через PHP

Tags: php, xml

Есть ссылка: http://ol.partners/api/ApiXml_v2/a10deef8-b1f1-4ad1-a4e9-86de5bbdad0c

Она отдает файл XML

Мне нужен скрипт, который бы мог сохранить данный файл на сервере(скрипт будет в дальнейшем пускаться в CRON). Файл должен заменяться более новым(с тем-же названием).

Тот, кусок кода, который у меня есть сейчас выглядит так(естественно он не работает):

```
    <?php    
          $file = "http://ol.partners/api/ApiXml_v2/a10deef8-b1f1-4ad1-a4e9-86de5bbdad0c"; //$_POST['link'] $_GET['link']
    
        if (!empty($file)) { 
    
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=XMLFile.xml");
             header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
             header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
             header('Expires: 0');
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
             header('Pragma: public'); 
    
                $xml_data = file_get_contents($file);
    
                $ch = curl_init($file);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
                $output = curl_exec($ch);
    
                curl_close($ch);
    
        }  
    ?>
```

Заранее спасибо. Знаю, что для большинства данная задача очень проста.

Comment: после первой строки кода где определена ссылка напишите что-то вида `file_put_contents("./data/out.xml", file_get_contents($file));`  а остальное все удалите. `"./data/"` замените на корректный путь, куда хотите сохранить, и позаботьтесь о том, чтобы данная директория была доступна для записи юзеру от имени которого будет работать скрипт.

Comment: Спасибо , удалось сформировать сам файл .xml. На хостинге он появляется в указанной директории, но почему-то пустой. Возможно, из-за размера файла его не успевает считать полностью?

Comment: не такой уж там большой размер файла (странно что сжатие не настроено) чтобы не успеть. более того, если бы не успело, то и файл бы не создался.

Comment: В чем может быть проблема и какие есть варианты её решения?

Comment: убедиться, что в коде указана корректная ссылка.  Проверить, что выдается в `print_r($http_response_header)` после загрузки. Формально, можно сделать сначала проверку, что данные были получены, а-ля `$data = file_get_contents($file); if($data === false){ print_r($http_response_header); }`, уже опотом записать в файл `else file_put_contents("./out.txt", $data);`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Скрипт изначально рабочий. На хостинге стояло ограничение на получение данных.

Answer (score 0):

после первой строки кода где определена ссылка напишите что-то вида

```
file_put_contents("./data/out.xml", file_get_contents($file));
```

а остальное все удалите. "./data/" замените на корректный путь, куда хотите сохранить, и позаботьтесь о том, чтобы данная директория была доступна для записи юзеру от имени которого будет работать скрипт